# How does the buildType block work in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Could anyone explain how the `buildTypes` block works in `Gradle`?

As far as I know, the debug block runs when it's in debug mode and the release block runs when it's in release mode.
But if I run my `Gradle` script, both of these blocks  run!

```
  buildTypes {
            debug 
            {
            print("running in debug mode")
            }
            release
            {
            print("running in release mode")
            }
     }
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programming language is Groovy and the BuildTypes block is a closure.

The file is interpreted in full and the flavors of your build are not if statements or otherwise conditionals, so both are printed at runtime